# iphone paint application

Tags: iphone

is there any complete source code available for developing a image editing,paintng application in iphone???if anyone knows plese help me

thankzz

Comment: Accept answers from your previous posts that solved your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Berkeley had a hw assignment. Students submitted them via wiki so maybe look at those?

http://vis.berkeley.edu/courses/cs160-sp10/wiki/index.php/Individual_Programming_Assignment_3

Comment: ok,,but want to increse the size of the brush by using slider,and also 5 brush shapes want to create also,,,triangle,rectangle,,thankz

Comment: I FINISHED PAINT BUTTONS WHICH COLOR SELECTION IS DONE,,I WANT TO IMPLEMNT THIS TO BRUSH,,I CAN CHANGE THE CORRESPONDING COLOR TO THE BACKGROUND BUT NOT ON THE BRUSH,,I JUST FINISHED THAT,,

Comment: can u give ur email id?then i can send the full discription to u,,this is more easy you to understand my requirnmnts

Comment: @Nipin You can't possibly be serious, please put at least *some* effort in your style. StackOverflow != MySpace

Comment: how to solve memmory allocation in ios ?give me the right way to solve memmory issues

Comment: Well, every time you retain, copy, or alloc an object, make sure you (auto)release it either at the end of the method call or the dealloc. Just gotta keep count

Answer (score 2):

GLPaint, available from Apple...

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GLPaint/Introduction/Intro.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007328-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2

Answer (score 1):

There is an application named TouchPainter and its source code is available. It contains drawing, color blending, Undo/Redo (Amazing..!!), Save/Open drawings..

Note : It may require very deep level knowledge of Objective C. The whole application's source code is explained in this book **"Apress.Pro.Objective-C.Design.Patterns.for.iOS.Mar.2010"**  available and source code is also available here :

http://www.apress.com/apple-mac/objective-c/9781430233305

I hope it will be helpful to you.. :) Good luck..