# Drawing with CoreGraphics

Tags: iphone, core-graphics, undo

I am using CoreGraphics to implement free hand drawing which is working fine for me and now I want to implement Undo feature for this drawing so that user can clear his last stroke.

Here is my drawing method which working UITouchesBegin and UITouchesMoved.

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *touch  = [touches anyObject];

    previousPoint2  = previousPoint1;
    previousPoint1  = [touch previousLocationInView:self];
    currentPoint    = [touch locationInView:self];


    // calculate mid point
    CGPoint mid1    = midPoint(previousPoint1, previousPoint2);
    CGPoint mid2    = midPoint(currentPoint, previousPoint1);

    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, mid1.x, mid1.y);
    CGPathAddQuadCurveToPoint(path, NULL, previousPoint1.x, previousPoint1.y, mid2.x, mid2.y);
    CGRect bounds = CGPathGetBoundingBox(path);
    CGPathRelease(path);

    drawBox = bounds;

    //Pad our values so the bounding box respects our line width
    drawBox.origin.x        -= self.lineWidth * 2;
    drawBox.origin.y        -= self.lineWidth * 2;
    drawBox.size.width      += self.lineWidth * 4;
    drawBox.size.height     += self.lineWidth * 4;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(drawBox.size);
    [self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    curImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    [curImage retain];
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    [self setNeedsDisplayInRect:drawBox];
}

-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [curImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
    CGPoint mid1 = midPoint(previousPoint1, previousPoint2);
    CGPoint mid2 = midPoint(currentPoint, previousPoint1);

    context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    [self.layer renderInContext:context];

    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, mid1.x, mid1.y);
    // Use QuadCurve is the key
    CGContextAddQuadCurveToPoint(context, previousPoint1.x, previousPoint1.y, mid2.x, mid2.y);

    CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, self.lineWidth);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, self.lineColor.CGColor);

    CGContextStrokePath(context);

    [super drawRect:rect];
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741880/iphone-paint-application

Comment: I tried as the code in Question but could not do it successfully. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6689600/undo-drawing-in-paint-application)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be 2 ways to implement this on my point of view

1. U can save paths in NSArray and draw all those in loop while calling `drawRect` method and then while undoing, remove last object, add it to buffer array and redraw all the arrays.
2. U can get one offline buffer canvas where you can have an image created while drawing points, update it when u draw it every time. Here also you need to create an array of points but not redraw then everytime. When you do undo, just remove last object and create a new buffer canvas while drawing points in array.

Comment: Thanks Dimple the first option is striking my mind but if you can elaborate it a little for me as I have also added UITouchesMoved method.